How to download attachment of type image in bulk
I have an Object of Case, where we will have related object named Defect_Rectification_Item__c.

Inside this defect object, we will have attachment of type image.



How can I download all the image in the attachment of the related Defect that I filter?

Can we sort of query Attachment based on ParentId of the list of Defect_Rectification_Item__c record and somehow get the query and have downloadable URL or something?


Thank you.

You are going to download in bulk? or you want the user's to be able to perform this from within case record page?

Would like to download in bulk, so far I have also tried make a webservice and calling it. In the process of doing so using this guide: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4EzsSAF
